# UNIX diff command usuage on puppet exec

Tags: linux, bash, exec, diff, puppet

I have 2 Release.ini file:

- one I am downloading from S3 storing in /CodeRootFolder/tmp location
- and other in /DocRootDir location

I want to verify if there are changes in downloaded (i.e. /CodeRootFolder/tmp/Release.ini) file, and if there is change then execute the rsync command via puppet exec as below.

The error is if there change, it does not executing, it seems to as diff returns 1.

```
exec {'Actual code deployment with rsync':
    command => "rsync ${myclass::CodeRootFolder}/tmp/* ${myclass::DocRootDir}/)",
    #cwd => "${myclass::CodeRootFolder}",
    onlyif => "diff --changed-group-format='%<' --unchanged-group-format='' ${myclass::CodeRootFolder}/tmp/Release.ini ${myclass::DocRootDir}/Release.ini",
    path => ['/opt/rh/php55/root/usr/bin','/opt/rh/php55/root/usr/sbin','/usr/local/sbin','/usr/local/bin', '/sbin/' ,'/bin/', '/usr/sbin/','/usr/bin/'], 
}
```

Is there a good solution to my problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error is if there change, it does not executing, it seems to as
>   diff returns 1.

Yes, that's correct.

> [Invoking `diff`](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Invoking-diff.html)
>
> An exit status of 0 means no differences were found, 1 means some
>   differences were found, and 2 means trouble.

If you want the command executed if there is change, you have to use `unless` instead of `onlyif`.